# Is there a way to make this code less horrendous? Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, division

So I'm trying to get a number to be divided simultaneously by 1 through 7.
How can I simplify the "if" part?

I'm a beginner so if possible make it simple to understand.

Thanks!

```
result = []

for _ in range(1, 9999):
    if _ % 1 == 0 and _ % 2 == 0 and _ % 3 == 0 and _ % 4 == 0 and _ % 5 == 0 and _ % 6 == 0 and _ % 7 == 0:
        result.append(_)

print(result)
```

Comment: You could also create and populate your list with list compressions in a single line of code.

Comment: Just a tip when asking questions. You can make code blocks easier by surrounding the code block with triple back ticks (``` both at the beginning and end of your code block). This is often easier than indenting all the code by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a variable you should NOT name it `_`, this character is used for when something needs to be assigned but is never used. Lastly, you are looking for the [`all(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) syntax I think:

```
result = []

for num in range(1, 9999):
    if all(num % x == 0 for x in range(1, 8)):
        result.append(num)

print(result)
```

or the one line:

```
result = [num for num in range(1, 9999) if all(num % x == 0 for x in range(1, 8))]
```

Comment: You guys are fast haha. Thanks!

Comment: If it answered the question don't forget to mark it as an answer so we know you don't need anything else. (Its the check mark under the voting arrows).